# Slow SQL query from app, fast from SQL Studio

Tags: sql-server, index, execution-plan, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a query that takes 30+ seconds when called from app, but takes <1sec when called directly from SQL SMS.

Here is the query :

```
SELECT T0.pk 
    FROM   products T0 
    WHERE  (( ( T0.pk IN (SELECT T1.target 
                               FROM   catrel T1 
                               WHERE  ( T1.source = 87960962008461 ) 
                                      AND ( T1.type = 87961011815221 )) 
                AND T0.pk NOT IN (SELECT T2.target 
                                       FROM   varexc T2 
                                       WHERE  ( T2.source = 87960962008461 ) 
                                              AND ( 
                                      T2.type = 87961020990261 )) ) 
               OR ( T0.pk IN (SELECT T3.target 
                                   FROM   varinc T3 
                                   WHERE  ( T3.source = 87960962008461 ) 
                                          AND ( T3.type = 87961021066258 
                                              )) ) )  ) 
           AND ( T0.type IN ( 87961022300198, 87916102426706 ) ) 
    ORDER  BY T0.p_code
```

I have no idea where to start debugging that. When run directly in the SQL databse, the response in instant :

[image: live query stat]

The query does appear in the "recent expensive queries" (only when run from another client)

*PS: SQL Server does not recommend any additional indexes.*

Comment: Did you happen to come across [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Yes but have only read the first couple chapters! Most (if not all) of the article talks about stored procedures which I thought does not concern me. I'll have a look again.

Comment: Are query plans different from each other? Look at the wait type column on sp_WhoIsActive when run query from application.

Answer (score 1):

The option PARAMETRIZATION was "forced" instead of "simple"
Switching back to simple + disabling Parameter Sniffing solved the issue.

Comment: Turns out the Erland Sommarskog articles are pretty darn thorough!